# How to get height of a TextFormField

Tags: layout, flutter

In flutter, how to get height of a [TextFormField](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html).

Comment: The Height of `TextFormField` depends on various properties that is set in `InputDecoration`. But why would you want to do it?

Comment: @HemanthRaj because fade animation require height.

Comment: @HemanthRaj But now figure out that `AnimatedCrossFade` does not require to compute height thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the size of any widgets using `context.size`. You can get a specific widget's context by setting a `GlobalKey` on the desired widget.